# Azure: After Uploading SSL CERTIFICATE through Application Gateway Listeners on azure ,URL is not hitting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf, azure-application-proxy

After creating Application Gateway Listeners and rules we have uploaded the SSL certificate(HTTPS) for Port:-443, but URL is not hitting.
we are using application gateway WAF , App services, we have configured Listeners, Http setting and rules but still URL is not hitting.
The same configuration is working perfectly on test environment. As the same we have configured on stage environment but this is not working.
Please suggest any setting we missed.
[Server id not hitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYjRU.png)

Comment: To check this first try to see in the f12 window network traces whats happening, whether routing happening or not? if not then check your configuration again

Answer (score 0):

As per the error screen shot its TCP_Error meaning its not hitting to SSL layer. Please make sure with the same backend you're able to connect over HTTP listener.

What is outcome of probe. Please make sure to refer probe result

Also I would suggest you to check "diagnose and Solve Problem" of Application gateway.
[image]

Comment: Hello @Rohit, thank you for your reply. As you have written "Please make sure with the same backend you're able to connect over HTTP listener.
What is outcome of probe. Please make sure to refer probe result"
1. So how can we validate these settings
2. And we have tried to run the "diagnose and Solve Problem", but did not get any luck still we are facing same issue.